# how can I apply a color map but to individual vertices (as flat colors)

Tags: color, shader-nodes

I'm in the shading tab (I'm fairly new to blender and don't know how to do much with nodes) and I can't figure out how to alter my nodes to flatten out as single colors to my verticies.[image: these are my nodes but I don't know how to get the colors not to fade.]

Comment: Sorry, just to clarify, you want each vertex to have a pink color, regardless of "distance" from the center of the sphere?

Comment: yea, something like a solid color, if this isn't possible thats fine, I can go on without it but I hope to get each vertex to somehow take the average "color" from all of the hues on its plane to get an individual color instead of a mixture of them.